# Content disappears when searching with Search & Filter plugin

Tags: plugins, search, content

I manage a website in which the plugin **Search & Filter** is being used to go through the content by visitors.

With a particular search query, the content appears correctly, soon to disappear seconds after. I've been trying to understand the problem without success.

What's more interesting is that the content is still on the page, but it doesn't show, and it's not being hidden with `display: none`. So the DOC is there on the page, available via developer tools, but not visible to the human eye. It's just white.

To add to the mystery, the problem only happens with one query, I tried other types of queries, and it's not a problem.

Things I tried before posting here a question:

- Updated all plugins.
- Updated the cache from the Search & Filter plugin.
- Tried other queries, the content is displayed correctly.
- Added a second parameter to the query, and it shows the content.
- There's a precise moment during the load of the page, in which a script is launched. It seems that the script is messing with the content. But this is just an assumption.

Maybe someone has an idea of what's going on? If you are curious, you can check the page with the problem here: https://media-pes.eu/search/?_sfm_pes_leader=218

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, as suggested by a member of my local community.

There was an **opacity set to 0** on the CSS as soon as the page loaded. Because of this new setting, the content would remain in the DOC, but "disappear" from the content.

Although the real root of the problem wasn't found after all (why the page was adding an opacity of 0 after loading), it was enough for me to bypass it by adding a new rule to the CSS and force opacity 1.